# Spark : How to create a map function that can take a batch of data rows, do some processing on each row and output a batch of modified rows

Tags: apache-spark

I have a data file with the following format

```
id
 0
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
```

I need to do the following on this file:

1) Divide the data in 4 buckets and stamp a bucket # to each row. The file should have the following format:

```
id Bucket Num
 0  0
 1  0
 2  0
 3  0
 4  1
 5  1
 6  1
 7  1
```

I used the following Scala code to do that:

```
val fileRDD = sc.textFile(inputFile).zipWithIndex()
                  .filter(_._2 > 0)
                  .map{case (k,v) => ((v/4).toString() + delimiter + k)}  
                  .map{_.split(delimiter)}
                  .map(s=>Row.fromSeq(s.toSeq))
```

2) I then need to read all lines of the file with a specific bucket number, run some business logic and create an output like this.

```
id Bucket Num  Emp Num
 0  0            1
 1  0            4
 2  0            2
 3  0            3
 4  1            3
 5  1            2
 6  1            4
 7  1            1
```

In the output above, a function needs to read in all lines of the file for a specific bucket #, do some business logic and stamp an Emp Num to each line of the data.

I am unable figure out a way to do step 2. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: I would start the second step by using `groupBy` method on `bucketNum` values. Then you would have RDD of 4 partitions of something like (bucketNum, CompactBuffer(record_0, record_1, ..., record_n). You would map over that CompactBuffer with your function then (it could even be a different function for different bucketNums). And here's the tough part (but definitely possible): going back from those 4 already processed partitions, to the full RDD. You could use `flatMap` method and convert every partition contents to List, which would "force" Spark to make original N partitions from those four.

Comment: If you could provide some fake/test data, I would write a full solution and post it here as an answer.

Comment: @Pawel I have modified the examples above with some data. Hope this helps you to write the code.

Answer (score 1):

Because you'll probably have multiple columns in your source file, I have extended the test data a little.

```scala
val sc: SparkContext = ...

val movies = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (0, "The Shawshank Redemption", 1994),
  (1, "The Godfather", 1972),
  (2, "The Godfather: Part II", 1974),
  (3, "The Dark Knight", 2008),
  (4, "Schindler's List", 1993),
  (5, "12 Angry Men", 1957),
  (6, "Pulp Fiction", 1994),
  (7, "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King", 2003)
))

val results = movies.map { case (id, movie, year) =>
  (id / 4, (id, movie, year)) // You can choose your own way of determining a bucket number
}.groupByKey().flatMap { case (bucket, records) =>
  records.map { case (id, movie, year) =>
    (id, bucket, movie, year, year + bucket + 1) // Instead of the `year + bucket + 1` you should place your own custom logic
  }
}

results.collect() foreach println
```

Output:

```
(0,0,The Shawshank Redemption,1994,1995)
(1,0,The Godfather,1972,1973)
(2,0,The Godfather: Part II,1974,1975)
(3,0,The Dark Knight,2008,2009)
(4,1,Schindler's List,1993,1995)
(5,1,12 Angry Men,1957,1959)
(6,1,Pulp Fiction,1994,1996)
(7,1,The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King,2003,2005)
```

Let me know if you'll have any troubles with understanding or using this solution.